# What does "nit" mean in hacker-speak?

Tags: shorthand, abbreviation

When someone writes "nit: removed whitespace" on a commit, what does "nit" mean? I've also seen it capitalized as if it were an abbreviation (i.e. NIT). For an example usage see [this post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7357149):

> Of course there is a difference between a comment saying: "Nit:
>   Trailing whitespace" and "According to Section V, Subsection VII of
>   the Coding Manual you should never add trailing whitespace. Please see
>   that you don't." or some stuff like that. The latter is a
>   passive-aggressive potshot, the former IMO is just a quick reminder.

Other example from ["Chromium Code Reviews"](https://codereview.chromium.org/9662):

> Issue 9662: fix minor style nit (Closed)

EDIT: And an answer comes from [Bugzilla's review page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Review):

> Sometimes the reviewer will prefix his comments with "Nit:". This
>   means that he's just "nitpicking"--you don't have to fix these points,
>   but we'd like you to.

Comment: A "nit" means a trivial item. If it's in caps, it may be an acronym. It depends upon context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming problem but a dictionary one.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In the context of "nit: removed whitespace," I would assume that the term is short for `nit-pick`.  That is, a small change that may not be very *important*, but is technically *correct*.

Answer (score 15):

It is short for "[nit pick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitpicking)".  Pretty sure.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, it means "a louse egg" - in context it indicates "a very small detail".

Answer (score 5):

NIT in this context means nit pick. Its generally used for small change requests and suggestions.

for more details you may refer to https://www.chromium.org/glossary

Answer (score 0):

The act of removing nits. Very small nonfunctional things. e.g. format, coding style, etc.

Answer (score 0):

shorthand for
NIT : (N)ot (I)mportant, (T)hough

Comment: I like this, even if I think this is not etymologically correct.